# Unable to access database docker container from the parent host

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-container

I was able to start an Oracle database Docker container successfully.  I am seeing the port information to access the database in Kitematic UI.
 Also I am able to ping the IP address (192.168.99.100) of the docker container as well. But when I try to access the database using the sql plus or sql developer, I get errors

Here is how I tried in sqlplus

```
sqlplus system/oracle@192.168.99.100:1521:xe
```

I got an error like below

```
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

I also tried accessing `sqlplus system/oracle@192.168.99.100:1521/xe` but I got error like below

```
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Looking at this error I see there is something wrong with the oracle TNS listener. But how do I fix that in case of running docker container?

Comment: Please, add the script you used to start your oracle database. Have you share your database port with your host ? `-p 1521:1521`

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron  I have used docker run -p 1521:1521 -p 8080:8080 imageName

Comment: Also I can see the port numbers as  192.168.99.100:1521 in the Kitematic as well. So I don’t think I made a mistake in the port numbers.

Comment: So the problem is maybe not related to docker but to sqlplus. Have you tried without `xe` :  `sqlplus system/oracle@192.168.99.100:1521` (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65032/connect-to-sql-plus-from-command-line-using-connection-string/96814)

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron I did tried without xe as well. I got some other error, but I couldn’t remember what was that error. Have to try one more time again ..

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron When i run with sqlplus system/oracle@192.168.99.100:1521        , i get this error                                                             ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor

Comment: go to your docker, login as oracle and do a : lsnrctl status
update you question with the output.

Comment: ORA-12514 means you can connect to the listener (in your docker container) but the listener doesn't know anything about the DB "Service" XE you want to connect to.
Check inside your docker if the DB ist running healthy and if it registers to the listener.

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO here is the output of the lsnrctl status                                                      Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=66a6ea68f5ee)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

Comment: Edit the listener.ora file located in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin and replace the hostname by the IP of your machine. Then restart the listener: lsnrctl stop; lsnrctl start

Comment: Also I can see from the output that the status is blocked for XE, check if your database is started

Comment: I get the following error when i try to do an sqlplus  inside the docker container where oracle is installed       
   sqlplus system/oracle@localhost:1521/XE                                                                            ERROR:
ORA-12528: TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new connections

Comment: I think oracle database is running. Because i am able to run the command sqlplus / as sysdba without any issues.

Comment: I found out the root cause of all these issues. I was running the oracle database inside a Docker container. Container runs on top of the Oracle virtual box. The default Virtual disk size was 20gb and it is almost filled up. Oracle was not able write the logs while starting the server .. when I increase my virtual disk space size, all these issues are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer was given by the OP as a comment here it comes as an answer:

> I found out the root cause of all these issues. I was running the
> oracle database inside a Docker container. Container runs on top of
> the Oracle virtual box. The default Virtual disk size was 20gb and it
> is almost filled up. Oracle was not able write the logs while starting
> the server .. when I increase my virtual disk space size, all these
> issues are fixed.

– babs84